# Block User access through URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a settings page in my app.

This should only be  configured by an Admin so I blocked the page from a normal Member.

```
  <security:authorize access="hasAuthority('Administrator')">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="/settings">
            <img src="../resources/img/icons/10.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
            <span class="menu-title">Settings</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    </security:authorize>
```

It works well. The user doesn't see the page. The problem is that if he access `/settings` he can see the page without a problem.

I want to show him a forbidden page instead. Any idea how to do this? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring security allows you to extend a `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which you can use nicely with spring boot like this:

e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/settings").hasAuthority("Administrator");
    }
}
```

Assuming that your Principal is being authenticated and placed into the spring security context, this should trigger the access denied handler.

You can configure this as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/settings").hasAuthority("Administrator").and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage(...)
                .accessDeniedHandler(...)

    }
}
```

Where you can configure either an access denied page or custom handler.

Comment: it works but throws error 404 for a Member. It should be error 403. My code: `.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errors/error403")`

Comment: I suspect that the handler is unable to find a servlet mapping for `/errors/error403`. If you navigate to that URI directly in the browser does that work? It might help to see the directory structure of your project.